# Recursive function for tuple

Tags: python

The question is suppose a bunny can hop at most 50 centimetres far. What is the smallest number of jumps it needs to take to reach the other side of the river?

The function should return the minimum number of jumps needed, or -1 if it is not possible for the bunny to reach the other side of the river.

```
rabbit((32, 46, 70, 85, 96, 123, 145)) # 3
```

However

```
 rabbit((40, 70, 150, 160, 180)) #-1 because 150-70 > 50
rabbit((30, 70, 75, 120, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200, 246, 258)) #7



def rabbit(rocks):
    if len(rocks) <= 1:
        return 0
    elif rocks[1] - rocks[0] >= 50:
        return -1
    else:
        return 1 + rabbit(rocks[2:])
```

I am not able to get -1 for the case when there is a step that is > 50. Why ?

Comment: Your else case is preventing that from coming out of the recursion.

Comment: However, `list` should be used instead of `tuple`. `tuple` is used for collection of which the each items have different meanings. But your `rocks` is just an array of rock offsets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
else:
    return 1 + rabbit(rocks[2:])
```

The above line has (at least) two problems:

1. It does not check the return value of the `rabbit` function.
2. `rocks[2:]` always jump two rocks? you should adjust this according to the rock values.

---

```
def rabbit(rocks, prev=0):
    if rocks[0] - prev > 50:
        return -1
    p = rocks[0]
    for i, x in enumerate(rocks):
        if x - prev > 50:
            ret = rabbit(rocks[i:], p)
            if ret >= 0:
                ret += 1
            return ret
        p = x
    return 1
```

usage:

```
>>> rabbit((32, 46, 70, 85, 96, 123, 145))
3
>>> rabbit((40, 70, 150, 160, 180))
-1
>>> rabbit((30, 70, 75, 120, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200, 246, 258))
7
```

Comment: I am not able to get 3 for rabbit((32, 46, 70, 85, 96, 123, 145)) if I were to use rocks[1:]

Answer (score 0):

How about this code?

```
import bisect


def rabbit(rocks, hop=50):
    if not rocks:
        raise ValueError('No rocks')
    step = rocks[0]
    steps = [step]
    while True:
        x = bisect.bisect_right(rocks, step + hop)
        step = rocks[x - 1]
        steps.append(step)
        if x == len(rocks):
            break
        elif rocks[x] - step > hop:
            raise ValueError('Too far between {0} and {1}'
                             ''.format(rocks[x], step))
    return steps
```

Here's the results:

```
>>> rabbit([32, 46, 70, 85, 96, 123, 145])
[32, 70, 96, 145]
>>> rabbit([30, 70, 75, 120, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200, 246, 258])
[30, 75, 120, 170, 200, 246, 258]
>>> rabbit([40, 70, 150, 160, 180])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
ValueError: Too far between 150 and 70
>>> rabbit([])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
ValueError: No rocks
```

You can get a number of steps by `len(rabbit(rocks)) - 1`.